# How to send a 5 digit number to arduino with Python 3.3 and pyserial (strange error)

Tags: python, serial-port, typeerror, pyserial

'Hello,
I'm kinda lost after several hours trying different things. I have included my code. I'm tring to get a 5 digit number to the arduino, but I get an error when trying to send a number range. I'm not a seasoned programmer, but I have quit a lot of experience with the arduino. I can receive from the Arduino with no problem.

A piece of the testcode:

```
import serial
import time
import struct

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM15',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)
time.sleep(3)
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#this will store the line
bline = []

while True:
    ser.write(10128)
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.write(10000)
    time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

The Error:

```
connected to: COM15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Danny/Documents/arachnoid-0.5/testreceive.py", line 19, in <module>
    ser.write(10128)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 75, in to_bytes
    for item in seq:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since serial communication is for bytes, you would need to convert the int to a byte string.  In python 3 this would need to be encoded.

I believe this should do it:

```
ser.write(str(10128).encode())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a string to `write`, not an `int`.

To get 5 digits always with leading zeros if necessary:

```
ser.write(str(100000 + 10128)[-5:])
```

The addition makes it a 6-digit number, and the `[-5:]` slices off the last 5 digits of the result. Of course that's the hacky way to do it, I keep forgetting how to use `format` to do it properly.

```
ser.write('{0:05d}'.format(10128))
```